# MongoDB, Mongoose, How to remove duplicate items from the doc.find results after populating that data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an array of items in my database, some of these items have an array called relatedItems, which are basically an array of IDs, and these IDs could match some of the items inside the same document. I can run populate to transform the array of IDs into an array of objects, where each object is the populated item with the matched ID. But I also want to remove those items from the main array of items. Here is the example of my data structure:

```
{
    "data": {
        "getItems": [
            {
                "title": "item 09",
                "_id": "5a56215426004a22c17ba733",
                "relatedItems": ["5a5621a526004a22c17ba773", "5a56214b26004a22c17ba72a", "5a56215326004a22c17ba732", "5a56215726004a22c17ba735"]
            },
            {
                "title": "item 10",
                "_id": "5a56215726004a22c17ba735",
                "thumbnail": {
                    "Key": ".../5a56215726004a22c17ba735/thumbnail.jpg"
                }
            },
            {
                "title": "item 11",
                "_id": "5a56215326004a22c17ba732",
                "thumbnail": {
                    "Key": ".../5a56215326004a22c17ba732/thumbnail.jpg"
                }
            },
            {
                "_id": "5a56216b26004a22c17ba747",
                "relatedItems": []
            },
            {
                "_id": "5a56216c26004a22c17ba748",
                "relatedItems": []
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And I am running the following code to populate the data:

```
let items = await ItemModel.find({ category }).limit(limit).sort({ itemOrder: 1 })
        .populate({path: 'relatedItems', select: '_id thumbnail'}).sort({ itemOrder: 1 });
```

But as you know, after populating, and I am going to end up having duplicate items (one copy in the related items array and one in the main array) like so:

```
{
    "data": {
        "getItems": [
            {
                "title": "item 09",
                "_id": "5a56215426004a22c17ba733",
                "relatedItems": [
                    "_id": "5a5621a526004a22c17ba773",
                    "thumbnail": {
                    "Key": ".../5a5621a526004a22c17ba773/thumbnail.jpg"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5a56214b26004a22c17ba72a",
                    "thumbnail": {
                    "Key": ".../5a56214b26004a22c17ba72a/thumbnail.jpg"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "title": "item 11",
                    "_id": "5a56215326004a22c17ba732",
                    "thumbnail": {
                    "Key": ".../5a56215326004a22c17ba732/thumbnail.jpg"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "title": "item 10",
                    "_id": "5a56215726004a22c17ba735",
                    "thumbnail": {
                    "Key": ".../5a56215726004a22c17ba735/thumbnail.jpg"
                    }
                }
                ]
            },
            {
                "title": "item 10",
                "_id": "5a56215726004a22c17ba735",
                "thumbnail": {
                    "Key": ".../5a56215726004a22c17ba735/thumbnail.jpg"
                }
            },
            {
                "title": "item 11",
                "_id": "5a56215326004a22c17ba732",
                "thumbnail": {
                    "Key": ".../5a56215326004a22c17ba732/thumbnail.jpg"
                }
            },
            {
                "_id": "5a56216b26004a22c17ba747",
                "relatedItems": []
            },
            {
                "_id": "5a56216c26004a22c17ba748",
                "relatedItems": []
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I would like to remove the copy from the main array, and currently, I have accomplished it via the following code:

```
let items = await ItemModel.find({ category }).limit(limit).sort({ itemOrder: 1 })
    .populate({path: 'relatedItems', select: '_id thumbnail'}).sort({ itemOrder: 1 });

Promise.all(items.map(async item => {
    if (item.relatedItems && item.relatedItems.length > 0) {
        Promise.all(item.relatedItems.map(async relatedItem => {
            related.push(relatedItem._id);
        }));
    }
}));
items = items.filter(item => !JSON.stringify(related).includes(item._id));
```

And it works, but I am wondering if there is a faster/safer or more MongoDB native way to do this?

**Edit**
One important downside to using my filter method is that `.limit(limit)` does not work properly anymore since the array will be trimmed down if it finds duplicates, the workaround is using `.slice(0, limit)` on the final array after filtering, but doesn't sound like it's the best way. Also I kinda feel I am going to run into some issues if I decide to add pagination to it too.